# Mockito.eq matcher seems to match against list reference, not value

Tags: java, list, unit-testing, reference, mockito

I have a method `addToClonedList(List)` in class `App` that calls method `add(List)` in class `Dependency`.  I want to unit test `addToClonedList(List)`, and I want to create a mock `Dependency` object (called `mockDependency`) and verify that the method `mockDependency.add(List)` is called with the correct argument.  However, since the `List` instance referenced by `clonedList` gets a new element (`100`) added to if after the call in question, Mockito thinks that the 2-element `List` was passed to the `mockDependency`, and the test fails.  In reality, the `List` passed to `mockDependency.add(List)` only contained one element when it was called.  Is this expected Mockito behavior?  Is there a more standard way to test that I've passed the correct `List` to `mockDependency.add(List)`?

See my code structure and test output below:

**main/java/App.java:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class App {
  Dependency dataLayer = new Dependency();

  void addToClonedList(List<Integer> integerList) {
    List<Integer> clonedList = new ArrayList<Integer>(integerList);
    dataLayer.add(clonedList);
    clonedList.add(100);
  }
}
```

**main/java/Dependency.java:**

```
import java.util.List;

public class Dependency {
  void add(List<Integer> integerList) {
    //
  }
}
```

**test/java/AppTest.java:**

```
import java.util.*;
import org.junit.*;
import org.mockito.*;

public class AppTest {

  @InjectMocks
  App app;

  @Mock
  Dependency mockDependency;

  @Before
  public void beforeEachTest() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void testWithVerify() {
    List<Integer> originalList = new ArrayList<>();
    originalList.add(1);

    app.addToClonedList(originalList);

    Mockito.verify(mockDependency).add(Mockito.eq(originalList));
  }
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.athenahealth</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockitotest</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testifyproject.mock</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Test output:**

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
mockDependency.add([1]);
-> at AppTest.testWithVerify(AppTest.java:25)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
mockDependency.add([1, 100]);
-> at App.addToClonedList(App.java:8)

Comparison Failure: 
Expected :mockDependency.add([1]);
Actual   :mockDependency.add([1, 100]);
```

Comment: I don't know exactly how the matching works, but I can imagine that mockito simply holds a reference to the value passed into the mock, rather than taking a copy. Does it work as expected if you remove the `clonedList.add` line?

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, if I remove the `clonedList.add` call, the test passes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As Andy Turner notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47705875/1426891), the problem is that Mockito only keeps a *reference* to the value passed, without cloning it. This makes sense, because it would be wasteful for immutable value objects like String, and would be practically impossible for certain references like Thread.

However, you can write your own Answer to make that copy yourself:

```
List<Integer> listSnapshot;

@Test
public void testWithVerify() {
  List<Integer> originalList = new ArrayList<>();
  originalList.add(1);
  Mockito.when(mockDependency.add(any())).thenAnswer(invocation => {
    listSnapshot = new ArrayList<>((List<Integer>) (invocation.getArguments()[0]));
  });

  app.addToClonedList(originalList);

  assertEquals(originalList, listSnapshot);
}
```

Comment: This is the approach I went with.  I agree that it would be wasteful to cache/clone immutable objects' values, but thought it was possible that Mockito might cache references to elements in collections.  Alas, it seems it does not.

Answer (score 2):

Mockito isn't magical.

When the `add` method is called on the mock, the mock simply holds onto a reference to the value of the parameter. The `eq` matcher then compares to see whether the parameter you pass into `verify` equals that value, using `equals`. It can't do any better than this because, in general, it doesn't know how to take a copy of the parameter.

If you modify the value passed into the mock afterwards, Mockito doesn't know that you've done this, and still just compares the two references using `equals`.

You call the method on the mock with `clonedList`, and then add a value into `clonedList`, but not `integerList`. As such, when you compare `clonedList` to `originalList` using `eq`, they are different, and hence the check doesn't pass.

As suggested, if you don't add to `clonedList`, the test passes; and you can then see that it's not comparing using `==` by replacing `eq` with `same` (the test will then fail).